# Как подключить style.css в Twig, чтобы не дублировать код в дочерних шаблонах?

Tags: css, twig

Как подключить файл `style.css` в шаблонизаторе *Twig*, чтобы не дублировать код в дочерних шаблонах?

Comment: вы на github видели руководство ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например есть базовый шаблон **base.twig**:

```
{# base.twig file structure #} 
<html>
    <head>
        {% block head %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />            
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Затем для того чтобы не дублировать код в дочернем шаблоне **child.twig** мы реализуем наследование от **base.twig**

```
{# child.twig file structure #} 
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block body %}
    <!-- тут контент который будет в body  -->
{% endblock %}
```

[Документация](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#template-inheritance)

Comment: не хочет он обращаться к css файлу. Вот если в base.twig добавить тэг <style> тогда все нормально

Comment: Может вы путь неверный указываете?

Comment: находится в папке (templates) вместе с шаблонами

Comment: стили должны быть в публичной папке, ведь браузер должен их скачать с сервера, иначе стили не будут применены к разметке.

Comment: Думаю это уже другая проблема и лучше всего по ней добавить отдельный вопрос в случае возникновения проблем